# Why is data passed by onActivityResult(int, int, Bundle) not type-safe Or why does Activity Result API make calling activity for result type-safe?

Tags: android, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult, activity-result-api

**Jetpack** offers a new solution, which is **Activity Result API**, to deprecate `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult` for `Activity`/`Fragment` passing data respectively.

One of the reasons is that **Activity Result API** `makes calling an activity for result type-safe.`

I am confused. `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` of `Activity`/`Fragment` has been used for a long time. About disadvantage like code coupling, separation of request and response, I knew.

But, how is data passed by `onActivityResult()` not **type-safe**?

Comment: Did you get luck to clear your question? I'm also confused now.